# Rootless "unshare -m" like bubblewrap?

Tags: mount, root, namespace, non-root-user

On my Linux host `unshare -m` refuse to go without root.

Bubblewrap `bwrap --dev-bind / / --ro-bind-data xxxx xxxx` and `bwrap --dev-bind / / --tmpfs` doesn't require root. (no setuid on `bwrap`)

How can I use mount namespace without root like bubblewrap (but I don't want to use bubblewrap)?

Comment: `bwrap` *does* require root — it’s setuid root.

Comment: @StephenKitt `ll \`which bwrap\`` got `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`. And `getcap` got empty. `stat -c "%a %U:%G %n"  \`which bwrap\`` got `755 root:root /usr/bin/bwrap`  .Why can't I see setuid on `bwrap`?

Comment: Ah, right, I was looking at Debian, but Fedora doesn’t have setuid root `bwrap` because its kernel doesn’t restrict user namespace creation (see [this issue](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap/issues/324) for details).

Answer (score 1):

You need a user namespace, for example `unshare -rm`.

Answer (score 0):

## Some do it your self options

(for if there is nothing that already exists).

- Write a wrapper in golang, and give it the needed capabilities.
- Write a wrapper in shell or python, the run with `sudo`. Then add an entry to `sudoers` so that you don't need a password. Then write another wrapper / alias so that it can be run without **typing** `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is remap directories in the file system as a non root user, and run the child process in an environment that is cleaned up on command exit, I believe you can use the `faketree` utility [available here](https://github.com/enfabrica/enkit/tree/master/faketree). You can read a [blog post describing it here](https://blog.enfabrica.net/different-file-system-views-for-different-tools-a425f13bb7f0).

Quoting from the documentation:

> - **Does NOT require root**, any user can run it as long as pid and user namespaces
>   are enabled on the system (and they are by default on most modern linux distros,
>   you can use the included test to verify).
> - **Runs commands with the same UID/GID of the user**, does NOT create a shell
>   that appears to run as root (can be overridden by flags)
> - **Does NOT require `LD_PRELOAD`, ptrace, or similar tricks**. It works with static
>   binaries as well as with binaries that require a modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or
>   `LD_PRELOAD`, or have protections to prevent tracing.
> - **Affects only the commands run within faketree**, which means you can run multiple
>   instances of faketree in parallel by the same user on the same system and with different parameters.
> - **Propagates environment variables and privileges correctly**, allowing even graphical
>   tools to run correctly within faketree.
> - **Does NOT rely on FUSE**, disk performance and performance are unaffected.
> - **Can override individual files**, including `/proc` and `/sys` files.
> - **Tries to handle signals correctly**, so integration in a CI/CD pipeline should be
>   straightforward. Sending SIGTERM to faketree will propagate to the children, and
>   faketree will correctly wait for all children and descendants to terminate before
>   exiting. A `kill -9` of faketree will guarantee all descendants being killed as well.
> - If the wrapped command calls realpath or checks the filesystem,
>   the command will see just a normal file system with mounts.